# Application won't launch. Breakpoints aren't hit. No exceptions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

My program worked fine up until 30 minutes ago when it just would not launch. I didn't change any code and all settings are the same. When I try to launch my application through visual studio it just does what it usually does then says "Ready". Nothing shows. If I try to debug the code by breaking it somewhere, the breakpoint says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version." Also visual studio freezes if I leave the supposedly running program going for longer that about a minute, then I have to end the visual studio task. There really isn't any code that I can show you for this.

What is going on and how can I fix it? Is my project corrupt somehow?

Comment: Clean and rebuild - it sounds like the source is out of synch.

Comment: @Plutonix Just did this and it didn't change a thing. It says "0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 skipped"

Comment: Check that you're still in debug mode.

Comment: Also try to restart Visual Studio. Also, before starting it again delete VS's temporary files (mainly .ncb).

Comment: @Dialecticus I have restarted Visual Studio over 10 times now. Where can I find temp file for VS?

Comment: @Mathemats I am definitely in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this happened to me I would do:

Check Configuration ( Debug vs Release vs other)
Check Platform (AnyCPU or ....)

Make sure that they both are Debug and AnyCPU
Save solution
Clean Solution

Build each project starting with the one that has no dependencies

** UPDATE **

You posted this message

> "0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 skipped" –

When you Clean, there should be no skipped projects in the process of rebuilding

Comment: Thank you just found it. Just cleaned everything again for the fifth time and it didn't skip it this time. Seems to have done the trick.